# SPSS 22 on Mac OS X won't open window on startup after reinstallation with concurrent license settings

Tags: macos

When I installed SPSS 22 on Mac OS X 10.9 everything went fine. I noticed that I had chosen the wrong licence type (single instead of volume) so I deleted SPSS with AppCleaner and removed the whole IBM folder from /Applications. After installing it again with the correct license server it won't show a window or error message on startup. The app just sits in the dock and clicking the icon does not open a new window. Any ideas where to start the troubleshooting? Anyone experienced the same?

Comment: Same thing happens on another mac of mine... the problem seems to be related to the use of a licence server. Someone using SPSS on OS X with this licence settings?

Answer (score -1):

I am experiencing the exact same thing. Won't open on my desktop monitor connected to my mac mini OR on my macbook air. urgh!

sometimes the initial box that say "IBM SPSS Statistics Version 20--

oh my gosh. As I was writing this out I realized it was trying to open the prior version that I had. I deleted this older version and now it's working. Try that!

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).